Xmodmap freezes KDE when connecting peripheral (usb and bluetooth)
Connecting any peripheral using USB or Bluetooth causes KDE to experience freezes. During the freeze, you can still move the mouse pointer, but clicking anything doesn't work. After about 20 seconds, Firefox works fine, but you can't use Alt-Tab. After approximately 40-60 seconds, everything goes back to normal. I'm using X11 KDE 6 Plasma on Linux Arch (btw). The issue seems to be caused by Xmodmap (removing it or switching to Wayland where it doesn't work fixes the issue). Is there any workaround? I really need my key remappings. I found two posts about the same issue, but they are unresolved.
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/xmodmap-user-configuration-freezes-pc-when-bluetooth-device-is-connected/98308
https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/g4at66/weird_freezing_issues_after_connecting_bluetooth/
